# Some Junit tests disappear when running in Jenkins

Tags: java, junit, jenkins

I have a question regarding running Junit test on Jenkins. I have a job that runs a group of tests. one of these tests is pretty much time/memory consuming. This test recursively goes over some files and tests them. (I am sure it does not do an infinite loop) From time to time, this test disappears. It does not even appear in console log of the job.

Does anyone know what can be the issue? I am running the junit test using "execute shell" where I invoke ant in there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what the issue was.

The JUnit test I was running on Jenkins was taking too big and was getting all the memory, resulting to a java heap problem. However, Jenkins was not reporting that exception.

I broke the JUnit into smaller tests and everything runs normally now.